# Restricting CSS within a particular div

Tags: css, html

I have a template having header and footer. In the body part I'm making a backend call and getting the response and inserting the response directly into the body. The response is a kind of html having css,js associated with it. The response css is overriding the existing css of the template having header and footer.

Is there any way to restrict my css within the body part alone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post your CSS?

Comment: Are you asking the response css?

Comment: Basically, you want to prevent your own css from the one which is being served from the response right?

Comment: The response CSS should not affect my template level CSS. The resposne CSS should be taking effect only for the response data not for the template

Comment: There is currently no straightforward way to do what you want except for putting the content in an iframe.

Comment: How to do it with Iframe?

Comment: Write `Inline` css is only way for this....but not suggested until you extremely required.

Comment: _The response css is overriding the existing css_ So rewrite the response css or the existing css so it doesn't (?)

Answer (score 0):

nest all of the styles you want to restrict to the div?

i.e

```
<div id="restricted"></div>

#restricted{
 your styles
}
```